# Passing array of structs to a function in Go

Tags: go

I have an object parsed from some XML file. It has struct type like this

```
type Report struct {
    Items []Item `xml:......`
    AnotherItems []AnotherItem `xml:......`
}
type Item struct {
    Name string
}
type AnotherItem struct {
    Name string
}
func (Item *Item) Foo() bool {
    //some code here
}
func (AnotherItem *AnotherItem) Foo() bool {
    //another code here
}
```

For each item i have to do smth like this:

```
func main(){
    //some funcs called to get the report object
    doSmth(report.Items)
    doSmth(report.AnotherItems)
}
func doSmth(items ????){
    for _, item : range items {
        item.Foo()
    }
}
```

Since i have different items with same function i want to have only one `doSmth` so i can't do just `doSmth(items []Item)`
And the question is - what should i write instead of "????" to get this working?
The only way i made it to pass report.Items into doSmth() was

```
func doSmth(items interface{})
```

But it throws me an error "cannot range over items (type interface {})"
And if instead of iteration i just put smth like

```
func doSmth(items interface{}){
    fmt.Println(items)
}
```

program print the list of my items

Comment: Did you try `(items ...)`?

Comment: compiler says `final argument in variadic function missing type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Replace `????` with `[]Item`: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/c_d8HUNyCE). It is just the same as how that variable `report.Items` is defined in struct `Report`.</strike>

Ok, yes that does change the question. The thing I thought of immediately was that you just needed to create an interface such as `Itemer` and have `[]Itemer` in the function definition of `doSmth`:

```
type Itemer interface {
    Foo() bool
} 

func doSmth(items []Itemer) {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately [this does not seem to be possible](https://play.golang.org/p/ujqkleIYy7). I then tried some other permutations including using `interface{}`, `[]interface{}` as well as variadic functions and I couldn't get anything to work.

After [doing some research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7153343/2325784) it turns out that Go will not convert the type of slices. Even if each element of a slice is an instance of an interface such as `Itemer` or `interface{}` it still won't do it. <strike>I could not re-find the source but apparently</strike> This is due to the fact that a new slice would have to be created and each element would have to be type cast individually from the old slice to the new slice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975763/2325784.

To me this suggests that a function such as `doSmth` is not possible.

The only thing I could suggest is to restructure the code. If you are willing to post more information about `Foo` and `doSmth` I can try to help with that.

Comment: sorry, my bad
forgot important details why i can't use Items type in declaration
added to question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use variadic function for this scope:

```
func main(){
    //some funcs called to get the report object
    doSmth(report.Items)
}
func doSmth(items ...report.Items){
    for _, item := range items {
        item.Foo()
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, my bad
forgot important details why i can't use Items type in declaration
added to question

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect: `undefined: report in report.Items`. Also, if you wanted to use a variadic function you would need to call `doSmth` like `doSmth(report.Items...)`.

Comment: `report` variable created earlier
kind of `report := getReport()`

Comment: Actually this error comes from the function definition not where the function is called: https://play.golang.org/p/rELz-hXgGC.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:** Nvm, this wont work. Forgot about the fact that go doesn't have inheritance.*

You could convert the array into a slice, and make the function take a slice as a parameter instead.

```
names := []string{"leto", "paul", "teg"}
process(names[:])

func process(names []string) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call like this type of array of struct values using basic array concepts :
In this example , []item should be called as item.Item[i].Unitprice

I hope u would got some idea

```
type UserItem struct {
    UniqueID string `json:"uniqueID" bson:"uniqueID,omitempty"`
    Item     []Item
}

//Item : ""
type Item struct {
    ProductName   string  `json:"productName" bson:"productName,omitempty"`
    UnitPrice     float64 `json:"unitPrice" bson:"unitPrice,omitempty"`
    Quantity      float64 `json:"quantity" bson:"quantity,omitempty"`

//main : ""
func main(){
    for i := 0; i < len(item.Item); i++ {
        SubTotal := item.Item[i].UnitPrice * item.Item[i].Quantity
        TotalTax := (item.Item[i].TaxPercentage / 100)
        TotalTax = SubTotal * TotalTax
        Tax := SubTotal + TotalTax
        fmt.Println(Tax)
}
```